# Supress Trello API Notification when renaming card

Tags: api, trello

I made a little program to synchronize our internal time reporting system with Trello (SCRUM addon) and everything works fine. It basically takes the estimated hours per card from Trello, synchronizes the cards name with our internal system and then updates Trello with the actual hours used per card.

The problem is that each update of the card names triggers a Trello notification. Is there any way to suppress this behaviour? Ideally I'd want our system to update the Trello board right away when someone reports some spent time but as it is there are too many unnecessary notification emails being sent.

I was thinking that it could either first remove all notifications, make the subject changes and then readd notifications or is there some way to globally tell Trello to ignore making notifications for changes done with the Trello API?

Kind regards
Mats Forsén

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that through the API, but a recent change to when notifications are generated means that this should no longer be a problem.